# What's the relationship between kernel object and WaitHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Below is the quote from a C# book:

> The WaitHandle class is a simple class whose sole purpose is to wrap a Windows kernel object handle. Internally, the WaitHandle base class has a SafeWaitHandle field that holds a Win32 kernel
> object handle. This field is initialized when a concrete WaitHandle-derived class is constructed. Each method call on a kernel object causes the calling thread to transition from managed code to native user-mode code to native kernel-mode code and then return all the way back.

I'm confused on which kernel object is associated with the WaitHandle. Below is an example from MSDN:

```
public class Example
{
    private static Semaphore _pool;

    private static int _padding;

    public static void Main()
    {       
        _pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Worker));
            t.Start(i);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(500);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread calls Release(3).");
        _pool.Release(3);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }

    private static void Worker(object num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} begins " +
            "and waits for the semaphore.", num);
        _pool.WaitOne();

        int padding = Interlocked.Add(ref _padding, 100);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} enters the semaphore.", num);

        Thread.Sleep(1000 + padding);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} releases the semaphore.", num);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} previous semaphore count: {1}",
            num, _pool.Release());
    }
}
```

When main thread executes `_pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);`, if `_pool`(semaphore inherits from WaitHandle) wraps a Windows kernel object handle, then this kernel object must be the current main thread's since `_pool` is created in the main thread. So when worker thread from thread pool start to execute `Worker` method which calls `_pool.WaitOne();` inside.

If we look at the quote "each method call on a kernel object causes the calling thread to transition from managed code to native user-mode code to native kernel-mode code and then return all the way back." then how does worker thread get blocked and waiting for signals from main thread which will call `Release`? How can a worker thread use other thread's kernel object to block itself? isn't that the worker thread needs to assocaite the semaphore with its own kernel object then call method on its kernel object to make itself blocked and wait for signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can a worker thread use other thread's kernel object to block itself?

The reason why a worker thread can access a handle that isn't their own is because that handle is a reference *windows kernel handle*.

**Windows Kernel Handles**
A windows kernel handle is an operating system wide handle that can allow [synchronization across domain boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Which is just a fancy way of saying that this 'handle' is some *object* can be seen by any thread, process, or program running on the same Windows operating system.

An easier way that I like thinking about it is to consider a rudimentary lock for a shared resource.

This lock traditionally works such that an array, using the [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) keyword and a `System.Object`, can be protected from multiple threads changing it's values at once.

Let's look at a short example of that

```cs
class Program
{
    private int[] sharedResource = { 1 };

    private object myLock = new();

    void Worker()
    {
        lock(myLock)
        {
           sharedResource[0] = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example we have a `Worker`, who locks `myLock` and uses the array to do stuff.

This, in a very simple sense does the same thing a `WaitHandle` does. The only difference being the *scope* and *implementation details*.

**Scope Differences**
The scope of `myLock` in my example is *anything that has access to `Program`'s private members.*

So any worker threads created that capture `this`(ie.. `Program`) would have access to `myLock` by default.

Let's compare that to a `WaitHandle`.

A wait handles **scope** is *operating system wide*. This means anything that can access the underlying kernel object, can be therefore use it to synchronize itself.

**Implementation Differences**
Where in my example we just declare a object and use it, `WaitHandle` goes through multiple levels to declare a handle (`myLock`) at the operating system level.

> each method call on a kernel object causes the calling thread to transition from managed code to native user-mode code to native kernel-mode code and then return all the way back

I find it best to wrap this into an analogy as explaining *domain boundries* can easily bog people down with the details.

Consider my first example like a house (`Program`) where a bunch of house mates live (`Worker` threads).

The head of the house (*Main Thread*), needs to have a bunch of chores done so he puts the list of chores (*`myLock`*) to be done on the counter. Any body with a key to the house can access the list so they can work together to finish it (*synchronize*).

Instead with a `WaitHandle` — the head of the house (*managed code*), exits the house and goes outside (*native-user mode*) and takes a bus down to city hall (*native kernel-mode*) and posts the work to be done on the bulletin board.

When the head of the house posts that note, any body who goes to city hall can also use the note to synchronize.

That's what your worker threads do when they have to use your `WaitHandle`'s methods like `WaitOne`. The have to go to the operating system, check the handle, wait around, and get on the bus and head back to do some chores.

This is why your worker threads can access the main threads handle, because that handle isn't actually owned by it, its just a sticky note (reference) that tells the workers to go down to city hall and get the note (lock).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and example. I think I misunderstand sth, I was thinking "kernel object" is thread kernel object which will be used by Windows OS to schedule threads. So just to confirm, "kernel object" in thread synchronization is not the one that used by OS to schedule to run a thread?

Comment: @whoisit You can see in [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_Semaphore.cs,19) that it makes a call to [CreateSemaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsemaphorea) which is a kernel object unrelated to the thread handle.